# Deadlock issue when using routine with channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I have issue when using Go routine with channel. The code looks like this:

```
func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go func (c chan int, x int) {
        c <- x
        fmt.Println(x)
        close(c)

        defer wg.Done()
    }(c,10)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

When run the code I got this error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

I cannot understand why this issue happens. Please help me to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 goroutines in your example: the main goroutine running the `main()` function, and the other you launch inside it. The main goroutine waits for the other to complete (to call `wg.Done()`), and the other goroutine blocks in the line where it attempts to send a value on channel `c`. Since nobody is receiving from that channel, and because that channel is unbuffered, this goroutine will never advance, so all your 2 goroutines will block forever.

Note that `defer wg.Done()` should be the first statement in the goroutine. If it's the last, `defer` won't make any difference.

If the channel would have a buffer of at least one, the send operation could proceed:

```
c := make(chan int, 1)
```

And output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/5v-g-xgnN-R)):

```
10
```

If we leave the channel unbuffered, there must be another goroutine that receives from the channel, e.g.:

```
wg.Add(1)
go func() {
    defer wg.Done()
    x := <-c
    fmt.Println("Received:", x)
}()
```

Then output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/DwXpf3eUCdm)):

```
10
Received: 10
```